# R Split Lists Takes A Long Time

Tags: r, algorithm, split, data.table

I have a `data.table` that I need to split into lists. Here is a sample data set:

```
testSet <- data.table(A = 1:2, B = 4:5, C = rep(7:8, times = 50), 
                        D = 9:10, E = 15:16, F = 24:25, G = 27:28,
                        H = 29:30, I = 32:33, J = 35:36, K = 1:50)
```

As you can see, it has 11 columns, each of which is numeric. I need to split by the values in 10 of the columns so that there are a list of lists created. I have created the following functional code (Macbook Air for reference):

```
system.time(testSetLists <- split(testSet, 
                list(testSet[["A"]], testSet[["B"]], testSet[["C"]],
                        testSet[["D"]], testSet[["E"]], testSet[["F"]], 
                        testSet[["G"]], testSet[["H"]], testSet[["I"]], 
                        testSet[["J"]])))

>    user  system elapsed 
    0.759   0.109   0.731
```

This works perfectly and gives me exactly the output I need. HOWEVER, when I increase the number range in just a single column, like in `A` in the following data set:

```
testSet <- data.table(A = 1:5, B = 4:5, C = rep(7:8, times = 50), 
                        D = 9:10, E = 15:16, F = 24:25, G = 27:28,
                        H = 29:30, I = 32:33, J = 35:36, K = 1:50)

system.time(testSetLists <- split(testSet, 
                list(testSet[["A"]], testSet[["B"]], testSet[["C"]],
                        testSet[["D"]], testSet[["E"]], testSet[["F"]], 
                        testSet[["G"]], testSet[["H"]], testSet[["I"]], 
                        testSet[["J"]])))

>    user  system elapsed 
    2.139   0.301   2.054
```

You can see that the time to execute just by adding 3 values to `A` tripled the processing time. Now what happens when I add more values to `B`, `D`, and `J`, like so?

```
testSet <- data.table(A = 1:5, B = 4:9, C = rep(7:8, times = 50), 
                        D = 9:14, E = 15:16, F = 24:25, G = 27:28,
                        H = 29:30, I = 32:33, J = 35:56, K = 1:50)

system.time(testSetLists <- split(testSet, 
                list(testSet[["A"]], testSet[["B"]], testSet[["C"]],
                        testSet[["D"]], testSet[["E"]], testSet[["F"]], 
                        testSet[["G"]], testSet[["H"]], testSet[["I"]], 
                        testSet[["J"]])))

>    user  system elapsed 
  179.356  21.311 176.562
```

As you can see, this solution is untenable when I have 100 or so unique data points in each column.

I can remove all the empty lists using this function:

```
testSetLists <- testSetLists[sapply(testSetLists, function(x) dim(x)[1]) > 0]
```

My question is this: How can I take the same input and get the same output without the extremely high CPU time? Any option within R is on the table.

Comment: Whoa.  Did you look at the lists you've created?  Is that really what you want?

Comment: Yes. I put each of the lists through a function where list order is important and each list has a unique set of values.

Comment: I get a data table in the first element, a data table in the last element, and 1022 empty data tables in between.

Comment: I use this function to clean out the empty lists: `testSetLists <- testSetLists[sapply(testSetLists, function(x) dim(x)[1]) > 0]`

Comment: Why not write a function to operate on a Data.table?

Comment: I use multiple datasets together in the function that I run. They must be as `lists`, not as `data.table`s

Comment: Are you aware of the `drop` argument of `split`? Add `drop=TRUE` to your split calls and you'll have two benefits: the empty element of the list will be dropped and the computation time will be orders of magnitude faster. The last computation took 44 *milliseconds* on my PC (that seems to be twice as fast as yours).

Comment: @nicola please put this as an answer so I can select it as the correct answer. You're the man!

Comment: @black_sheep07 I made an answer. Glad it helped.

Comment: I think I read that there's a new `split` method for data.tables in the development version (which would likely be more efficient)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the computation  took so long because `split` tries to determine each *combination* of the factors provided. However, the `drop=TRUE` argument can be set, so only the combinations which have elements are kept. On your last dataset, on my PC:

```
system.time(testSetLists <- split(testSet,testSet[,.SD,.SDcols=names(testSet)[1:10]]))
#   user  system elapsed 
#128.111   0.343 128.930
system.time(testSetLists <- split(testSet,testSet[,.SD,.SDcols=names(testSet)[1:10]],drop=TRUE))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.048   0.000   0.048
```

Also notice how I took the columns that indicate the split, instead of writing manually one at the time.

Comment: Unfortunately the columns I split aren't consecutive, otherwise I would. Thank you though!

Comment: They don't need to be. Store their names in a vector, for instance `cols<-c("col1","col2",...)` and then use `testSet[,.SD,.SDcols=cols]`.

Answer (score 2):

Recently data.table gets own `split` method. It can accept column names to split by. There is no need to pass full columns to `f` argument, as in case of data.frame. It can also preserve order of grouping, unlike `split.data.frame`.

```
library(data.table)
suppressWarnings( # OP data raises recycling warning
    testSet <- data.table(A = 1:5, B = 4:9, C = rep(7:8, times = 50), 
                          D = 9:14, E = 15:16, F = 24:25, G = 27:28,
                          H = 29:30, I = 32:33, J = 35:56, K = 1:50)
)
system.time(dropF <- split(testSet, testSet[,.SD,.SDcols=names(testSet)[1:10]]))
#   user  system elapsed 
#371.684   4.032 115.058
system.time(dropT <- split(testSet, testSet[,.SD,.SDcols=names(testSet)[1:10]], drop=TRUE))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.304   0.004   0.097 
system.time(byDropT <- split(testSet, by=names(testSet)[1:10], drop=TRUE, sorted=TRUE))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.180   0.000   0.061 
all.equal(
    dropT[sort(names(dropT))],
    byDropT
)
#[1] TRUE
```

To install 1.9.7 version use:

```
install.packages("data.table", type = "source", repos = "https://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table")
```

Comment: `system.time(splitg <- split(testSet[, .g := .GRP, by=c(names(testSet)[1:10])], by=".g", keep.by=FALSE))` is also pretty fast. Not sure how to verify it is correct, but `setequal(splitg, byDropT)` is TRUE.

Comment: @Frank does `sequal` on lists even works? ah, oh, `setequal` not `fsetequal`